# How to create a Macro to compare A1 in 2 worksheets and copy adjacents contents

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets (WS1 is "ImportWS" and WS2 is "Disco + BLScope", there are names in column A in both worksheets and both have a column B with a value like Jumps high or still cant jump high).  I need to compare WS Disco + BLScope column A with ImportWS Column A and if a match is found then copy the adjacent value in WS ImportWS Column "B" to WS Disco + BLScope Column "B" on the respective matched row and then continue to see if there are more updates in WS ImportWSand repeat.

In a perfect-world, a pop up would appear at the end stating how many updates were found/made.

I have tried Vlookups but that doesn't work as I want to keep the value in WS Master if a match is not found.

I found this code (which does the core of what I need) which I tried to adjust but I get a run time error on the "lassrowAdd" line:

```
Sub CopyAdjacent()

Dim colStatus, lastrowAdd, lastrowRemove As Integer

colStatus = 2
lastrowAdd = Sheets(“ImportWS”).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrowAdd
        If Sheets(“ImportWS”).Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets(“Disco + BLScope”).Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            Sheets(“Disco + BLScope”).Cells(i, colStatus).Value = Sheets(“ImportWS”).Cells(i, colStatus).Value
        End If
Next
End Sub
```

So basically the end result would be:

The worksheet Disco + BLScope would have an updated value in the respective column B rows if an update is found in worksheet ImportWS.

At the end of the macro a popup to appear (this is totally optional) stating how many updates were found/made.

Hope that made sense, been trying for hours but cant crack it, your help would very much be appreciated.

Comment: With this line `Dim colStatus, lastrowAdd, lastrowRemove As Integer`, only `lastrowAdd` will be a `Integer`. 
You have to write ```Dim colStatus As Integer, lastrowAdd As Integer, lastrowRemove As Integer```

Comment: In my computer your line `lastrowAdd = Sheets(“ImportWS”).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` works fine. May be put a break point and look wath's going on ?

Comment: @HippolyteBRINGER only `lastrowRemove` will be `Integer`. The others will be declared as `Variant` type.

Comment: Ah Yes my bad, i don't copy/paste correctly !  `lastrowRemove ` will be a Integer